# DataGrid in WPF selectedRow

Tags: c#, wpf, database, datagrid

I have DataGrid (Not dataGridView!) in WPF application.
I want to selectRow and delete it. In datagridView I did this line to take the row I clicked on:

```
IkunsTableDB.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value
```

and in dataGrid I dont know how to take the row I selected on.
I tried this line in dataGrid but with no success :

```
int.Parse(dataGridIkuns.SelectedValue.ToString())
```

I need to delete update and save items to database.
So i success to load the DataBase (ACCES) and I dont know how to continue.. Thanks..

EDIT :: My XAML DataGrid code :

```
  <my:DataGrid Grid.Column="2"
                     Grid.Row="1"
                     Height="153"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                     Name="dataGridIkuns"
                     VerticalAlignment="Top"
                     Width="645"
                     Margin="0,6,12,0"
                     AutoGenerateColumns="True"
                     FlowDirection="RightToLeft" 
ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}"
                     SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" />
```

Comment: did you also tried `SelectedItem`?

Comment: Yes, it gives me that error : 
no value given for one or more required

Comment: I also tried : 
dataGridIkuns.SelectedIndex;        but it doesnt delete.. when I do  i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();        then i = 0 and it doesnt delete.

Answer (score 1):

The selected row can be found in the `DataGrid.SelectedItem` property. Therefore, you should create a new property, let's say that you name it `SelectedItem` too, and then data bind your new property to the `DataGrid.SelectedItem` property... If you have data bound a collection to the `DataGrid.ItemsSource` property, you can remove the item by simply removing it from that data bound collection (I'm assuming that you have data bound a collection property named `Collection`... if you haven't, create one and do this):

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" />
```

...

```
Collection.Remove(SelectedItem);
```

If you have added your items using the `DataGrid.Items` property (not such a good idea), then you can remove the selected item like this:

```
dataGridIkuns.Items.Remove(SelectedItem);
```

If you don't know about data binding, you'll need to read through the [Data Binding Overview‎](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN to find out how to do this. A look through the code examples in the [`DataGrid` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN should also help you.

Comment: didn't understand sorry, can you explain better please? where to add this code ? I eddited my XAML code datagrid .. can you help me please?

Comment: What exactly did you not understand? Do you know how to data bind?

Comment: Not exactly, I added your line to dataGrid XAML,but now in the code c# what to do to get the row i selected on ? I have been editted the XAML code again. See if this good ? The variable SelectedItem or Collection isn't found in the code..

Comment: I have been created the line collection and selectedItem. But it doesn't show it in the c# code.